# Facebook access_token failure from node.js

Tags: facebook, node.js, facebook-graph-api

I got this error while trying to get facebook **access_token** from **node.js** server:

> {"error":{"message":"(#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist
>   : access_token","type":"OAuthException","code":803}}

Following is the code for getting access_token:

```
var options={
        host:'graph.facebook.com',      
        path:'oauth/access_token?client_id=MYAPPID&redirect_uri=http://127.0.0.1:8000/&client_secret=MYAPPSECRET&code=CODEOBTAINEDFROMFB'
}
http.get(options,function(res){
    res.on('data', function (chunk) {
        console.log('BODY: ' + chunk);
    });
});
```

Request for the same url from my browser is working fine and I am getting the access_token also. what is the prob here?

**Update**
This may be the most funniest thing I have experienced from node.js. I have updated the above code as:

```
var http=require('http')
var options={
        host:'grah.facebook.com',       
        pathname:'/oauth/access_token',
        search:'client_id=MYAPPID&redirect_uri=http://127.0.0.1:8000/&client_secret=MYAPPSECRET&code=CODEOBTAINEDFROMFB'
}

http.request(options,function(res){
        console.log('http fb code')
         res.setEncoding('utf8');
    res.on('data', function (chunk) {
        console.log('BODY: '+chunk);
    });     
});
```

And what happening is server throw an error called **socket hang up**. Also my network  connection(internet connected via mobile modem) breaks out immediately! While Googling this issue I found a lot similar to this, but can't find the perfect solution...

Comment: Updated version of your code uses wrong hostname for Graph API. It's **graph**.facebook.com not **grah**...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with http object. Facebook only allows **https** while requesting with **client_secret**.
so this can work as I expected:

```
var options={
        host:'graph.facebook.com',      
        path:'/oauth/access_token?client_id=APPID&redirect_uri=http://127.0.0.1:8000/&client_secret=CLIENTSECRET&code=FBUSERCODE'
}       
var https=require('https'); 
https.get(options,function(res){
        console.log('http fb code')
         res.setEncoding('utf8');       
         res.on('data', function (chunk) {
                console.log('BODY: '+chunk);
        });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

[HTTP documentation](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback) lists `path` as option but states:

> `options` align with [`url.parse()`](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/url.html#url_url_parse_urlstr_parsequerystring_slashesdenotehost)

You should use `pathname` (and `search` for query string) instead of `path` while creating your URL. Also see [`URL` in documentation for node.js](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/url.html#url_url)

```
var options={
  host:'graph.facebook.com',      
  pathname:'oauth/access_token',
  search: 'client_id=MYAPPID&redirect_uri=http://127.0.0.1:8000/&client_secret=MYAPPSECRET&code=CODEOBTAINEDFROMFB'
}
http.get(options,function(res){
  res.on('data', function (chunk) {
    console.log('BODY: ' + chunk);
  });
});
```

**Update:**
In description of URL object in [`url.format()`](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/url.html#url_url_format_urlobj) documentation doesn't list `path` as option so it's probably only returned by [`url.parse()`](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/url.html#url_url_parse_urlstr_parsequerystring_slashesdenotehost)

Node documentation on URL states:

> `path`: Concatenation of pathname and search.